# Reference for learning web socket

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, sockets, websocket

I want to write a web socket client in javascript and web socket server in ruby.

Where shall I start? are there any existing libraries to reduces my work?

I'm lost and confused googling. Please provide any links where to start, given that has knowledge on ruby, javascript, basic networking in ruby.

Comment: you can start by googling around. come back when you hit a wall with your code.

Comment: http://socket.io/ can be a start. Though it works with node.js.

Comment: @intellidiot I wanted the server to be in ruby so socket.io is not the correct option for me, I've decided to use em-websocket http://www.igvita.com/2009/12/22/ruby-websockets-tcp-for-the-browser/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i currently using [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket)

```
EventMachine.run {

    EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|
        ws.onopen {
          puts "WebSocket connection open"

          # publish message to the client
          ws.send "Hello Client"
        }

        ws.onclose { puts "Connection closed" }
        ws.onmessage { |msg|
          puts "Recieved message: #{msg}"
          ws.send "Pong: #{msg}"
        }
    end
}
```

for more info see another thread about [ruby & websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767268/best-ruby-on-rails-websocket-tool):

Comment: also I found this article http://www.igvita.com/2009/12/22/ruby-websockets-tcp-for-the-browser/ about em-websocket

Answer (score -1):

As @intellidiot said, [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) could be the library you're looking for.

That code sample from their front page will tell you wether it's worth digging into it:

```js
 /* 
  *     Here is an example of a simple TCP server 
  *     which listens on port 1337 
  *     and echoes whatever you send it: 
  */

var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

See their website and doc. You can also look for [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) here.

---

**Edit :**

Of course this sample demonstrates server capabilities, but from this you can extrapolate to client capabilities involving the same kind of objects...

Here is a code sample from the [socket.io-client README](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/blob/master/README.md) ([socket.io-client](http://search.npmjs.org/#/socket.io-client) is a node.js package) :

```js
/*
 *    And now for the requested CLIENT code sample ;-)
 */

var socket = io.connect('http://domain.com');
socket.on('connect', function () {
    // socket connected
});
socket.on('custom event', function () {
    // server emitted a custom event
});
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    // socket disconnected
});
socket.send('hi there');
```

Hope this helps clarify. Sorry my answer was not as straightforward as it should have been in the first place.

Comment: He said : "web socket server in **ruby**"

Comment: he wants ruby websocket implementation

Comment: Yes server in ruby not in javascript

Comment: I should certainly have made it more explicit in my answer that _in my belief_, a JavaScript library with which you can use sockets to create a server **is certainly one you can use sockets to create a client too**. Have a look at this [node.js + socket.io tutorial](http://howtonode.org/websockets-socketio) for a code sample that more explicitly shouts "that's what you want". Will update my answer  to make it more obvious.

Comment: @pahnin Edited my answer, with a client node.js code sample